# how to delete all messages from rabbitmq using node library?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I want to delete all the messages from the rabbit mq queue before i start pushing data in it. How can this be achieved ? I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there's a `purgeQueue` method: http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_purgeQueue

```
channel.purgeQueue("some.queue");
```

Answer (score 1):

[purge_queue](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_purgeQueue) can be used to remove all undelivered messages from the queue named.

```
purgeQueue(queue, [function(err, ok) {...}])
```

Remove all undelivered messages from the queue named.messageCount, containing the number of messages purged from the queue is returned.

You can also do this using command-line:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl purge_queue queue_name
```